# Dictionary comprehension with nested list, prevent overwrite

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to use a dictionary comprehension using a nested list. As long as the keys are unique, all works fine. However if there are multiples of the key present I would like to append the values to that key instead of overwriting the value. Is this possible using a comprehension?

```python
seq1 = [[1, [1,2,3,4]], [2, [5,6,7]]]
seq2 = [[1, [1,2,3,4]], [1, [5,6,7]]]

print {key: [val] for key, val in seq1}  # Or dict(seq1)
>>> {1: [[1, 2, 3, 4]], 2: [[5, 6, 7]]}

print {key: [val] for key, val in seq2}
>>> {1: [[5, 6, 7]]}  # First value is overwritten

# Desired output:
def index_reads(reads):
    result = {}
    for i in reads:
        d = dict([i])
        for key, val in d.iteritems():
            if key in result:
                result[key].append(val)
            else:
                result[key] = [val]
    return result

print index_reads(seq1)
>>> {1: [[1, 2, 3, 4]], 2: [[5, 6, 7]]}

print index_reads(seq2)
>>> {1: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]}
```

Sorry, I couldn't find a repeat of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `groupby` from `itertools`.

```
import itertools
import operator

seq1 = [[1, [1,2,3,4]], [2, [5,6,7]]]
seq2 = [[1, [1,2,3,4]], [1, [5,6,7]]]

def index_reads(seq):
    return {k: [i[1] for i in g] for k, g in itertools.groupby(seq, operator.itemgetter(0))}

print index_reads(seq1)
print index_reads(seq2)
```

Output

```
{1: [[1, 2, 3, 4]], 2: [[5, 6, 7]]}   
{1: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need list comprehension. As a more pythonic way you can use [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method :

```
>>> d={key: [val] for key, val in seq1}
>>> for key, val in seq2:
...   d.setdefault(key,[]).append(val)
... 
>>> d
{1: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]], 2: [[5, 6, 7]]}
```

You can also use `collections.defaultdict` for such tasks.

Also it shows its power when you have different keys in `seq2` for example :

```
>>> seq2 = [[1, [1,2,3,4]], [5, [5,6,7]]]
>>> d={key: [val] for key, val in seq1}
>>> for key, val in seq2:
...   d.setdefault(key,[]).append(val)
... 
>>> d
{1: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]], 2: [[5, 6, 7]], 5: [[5, 6, 7]]}
```

And if you don't want to keep duplicates you can use a `defaultdict` with `set` as container :

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> seq1 = [[1, [1,2,3,4]], [2, [5,6,7]]]
>>> seq2 = [[1, [1,2,3,4]], [1, [5,6,7]]]
>>> 
>>> d=defaultdict(set)
>>> for key, val in seq1+seq2:
...   d[key].add(tuple(val))
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {1: set([(5, 6, 7), (1, 2, 3, 4)]), 2: set([(5, 6, 7)])})
```

Comment: or use a `defaultdict`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Yeah,indeed ;)

Comment: Thanks I will take a look, but the output is slightly different from the expected. I will edit now, sorry.

Comment: @kezzos So what you expected?

Comment: I want to process the lists individually, if seq1 didnt exists in the example. If I do d={key: [val] for key, val in seq2} the value is overwritten

Comment: @kezzos Sorry i don't get what you mean by `process the lists individually` you can do any thing on your list also when you loop over it when using `setdefault` or `defaultdict`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,with defaultdict works also:

```
from collections import defaultdict

seq1 = [[1, [1,2,3,4]], [2, [5,6,7]]]
seq2 = [[1, [1,2,3,4]], [1, [5,6,7]]]

d={key: [val] for key, val in seq1}
d = defaultdict(list)
for key, val in seq2:
    d[key].append(val)

print d
```

Then:

```
[(1, [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]])
```

Or if we delete seq1,

```
seq2 = [[1, [1,2,3,4]], [1, [5,6,7]]]
d={key: [val] for key, val in seq2}
d = defaultdict(list)
for key, val in seq2:
    d[key].append(val)
print d
```

Again you will have:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]})
```